# What is the definition of this quotient ring: $Z[x]/(3, x^{n}-1)$?

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, quotient-spaces

While reading a paper I came up with the following quotient ring definition but I am not sure what it does exactly mean:

$R=Z[x]/(x^{n}-1)$ ---> I know this one, since it has one quotient parameter which is $x^{n}-1$

$R/3=Z[x]/(3,x^{n}-1)$---> But this one has more than one qutient parameter, one is 3 and the other one $x^{n}-1$. What does this exactly mean?

Does it mean that we take the modulo of the elements of $Z[x]$ according to $x^{n}-1$ and then take the modulo again according to 3? If so, does that mean  $Z[x]/(3,x^{n}-1)=Z_3[x]/(x^{n}-1)$?

In other words do we take modulo $x^{n}-1$ of the elements of $Z_3[x]$?

Edit: Does it make any difference if i change the polynomial $x^{n}-1$ to $x^{n-1}+ x^{n-2}+...+1$  or to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you have doesn't seem to be "What is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, x^{n-1})?$" so much as it seems to be "What is $(3, x^{n-1})$? To put it shortly, it is the smallest ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that contains $3$ and $x^{n-1}$.

To put it a little bit more clearly, it is the set of all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(x) = 3q(x) + x^{n-1}r(x)$. To put it even more explicitly, it's the set of all polynomials where the first $x^{n - 2}$ terms have a coefficient divisible by $3$.

Put together, and skipping a lot of machinery in the background, you are right. $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, x^{n-1}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^{n - 1})$.

Comment: I just realized that i made a mistake in the question.  I have editted it above. It is $x^n−1$ not $x^{n-1}$. Does it change the result? I have also $x^n−1+x^n−2+..+1$ in another case. I mean does it make any difference of what the polynomial is in the quotient? Is it still equivalent to $Z_3[x]/...$?

Comment: @Esra no, that doesn’t make a difference. Just replace $x^{n-1}$ with $x^n-1$ in the answer, and it will still work

Comment: @Qwertiops thanks!